# Inserted data is different from actual data being sent

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I am trying to insert data into my Postgres Database, I am able to insert some data which is something else but not the actual data

This is my data generator and data sender into my query execution function(
(Python-Falsk)

```
def runid():
    cmdStr = 'cd /root/Dart/log; ls -rt DartRunner*.log | tail -1 '
    ret = execCmdLocal(cmdStr)
    logName = ret[1].strip()
    runId = ""
    print('The DartRunner Log generated is: %s'%logName)
    with open('/root/Dart/log/' + logName, "r") as fd:
         for line in fd:
            if 'runId' in line:
               runId = line.split()[-1]
               print('Run Id: %s'%runId)
               break
    print (runId) # output : Run Id: 180628-22
    post_runid(runId) # output is given in below link
    return jsonify({"run_id": runId})
```

This my database(postgres) execution method:
(Python)

```
 def post_runid(run_id):
     query = "insert into runid(runid) values(%s)"
     cur.execute(query %run_id)
     conn.commit()
```

My output looks something like this:
[The above two rows are manually inserted by me but the below two rows are executed from the code, the below two rows must be same as the above ones but for some reason they are not as the original data but being generated in series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7oOG.png)

Comment: try `cur.execute(query, run_id)` instead, this should save you from sql injection. else change your query to have `values('%s')` so that there is not formatting issue!

Answer (score 0):

Changing `%s` to `'%s'` in the query fixed the problem.

```
def post_runid(run_id):
     query = "insert into runid(runid) values('%s')"
     cur.execute(query, (run_id,))
     conn.commit()
```